# Using Doob's submartingale inequality

Tags: probability, martingales, random-walk

Let $X_n$ be a simple random walk on the discrete torus $\Bbb{T}_N^d$,

$K \subset \subset \Bbb{Z}^d $ and $K^*=\phi(K)$, with $\phi:\Bbb{Z}^d \to \Bbb{T}_N^d$

Let also $H_A= inf\{n \ge0: X_n(\omega)\in A\}$ and $T_A= inf\{n \ge 0: X_n(\omega)\notin A\}$

How do I use Doob's submartingale inequality to go from the first limit to the second one?

for any $x\in K$

$lim_{N \to \infty}P_x[H_{\phi^{-1}(K^*)\setminus K}\le n]=0$

for any $x\in K$  and for any $\epsilon>0$

$lim_{N \to \infty}P_x[T_{B(x,n^{(1+\epsilon)/2}) }\le n]=0$